# Past Continuous in reported speech

Tags: past-tense, speech, perfect-aspect, continuous-aspect

Let's imagine someone has told me:

> Last month while we were traveling in Cyprus, my mother was packing her bags for her first ever foreign trip.

I was wondering whether I could paraphrase it, and make it in reported speech:

> He told me his mum ___ her bags when they ___ in Cyprus.

Should it be two Past Perfect Continuous sentences?  I'm afraid it could be wrong here.

Comment: Such a confusing example, involving someone packing for a first trip while already apparently on a trip.  Or does the mother live in Cyrpus?  Who is "we" - does this include the mother?  It's hard to advise on grammar without understanding the sentence.

Comment: For a "while" clause, it's clear that the action is at the same time as the main clause, so you don't need to put it in past perfect. "He told me his mum had been packing her bags while they were traveling in Cyprus.

Comment: “He told me that while they were traveling in Cyprus, his mother was packing her bags for her first-ever foreign trip.” This does not resolve the ambiguity; it is reasonable to assume that we/they are the speaker and a companion other than his mother.

Comment: @cruthers we is "me and my wife" for example. Mother is the third person. And she was going to another country. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks for the answer. What if it's a "when" clause, not a "while" one? 
-He told me his mum had been packing her bags when we had been travelling in Cyprus a month before,

Comment: You don't have to put the verb in most *while, when, after, before, during,* etc. clauses in past perfect, because the prepositions make the order of events clear. You *can* put them in past perfect (but we usually don't), and you can probably come up with situations where you have to.

Comment: @PeterShor: But, the opposite also seems to be true here: "He told me that while he and his wife had been traveling in Cyprus, his mother was packing her bags for her first-ever foreign trip." This also works!

Comment: @PeterShor Why would we ever put the main clause in the Past Perfect Continuous then? Just to emphasise it was before the "He told" clause? Is it confusing if we leave it in Past Continuous? "He told his mum was packing her bags while they were travelling in Cyprus".
On the other hand it looks ambiguous, because it looks like his mum was packing her bags when he told that, which is not right, because we;ve got to mention it was before that.

Comment: @AlexanderSvetochev: we would put the main clause in the Past Perfect Continuous to show that it is before something we were talking about in the previous sentence. The choice of which tense to use in English is not governed solely by the sentence it is in; you need the full context.

Comment: @PeterShor thank you!